# Output of gulp-sass is .scss files not css files

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to compile some .scss files into css using gulp. gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task("sass",
function() {
    return gulp.src("app/assets/sass/*.scss")
     .pipe(sass({
                includePaths: [
                    "govuk_modules/govuk_frontend_toolkit/stylesheets/",
                    "govuk_modules/govuk_template/assets/stylesheet/",
                    "govuk_modules/govuk-elements-sass/"
         ]
        }).pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/stylesheets/")));
});
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and when I run the sass task in task explorer, I get the expected files output into the destination folder, however, they are .scss files and not the expected .css files.

There are some 20+ files in total in the paths, and these do get compiled in to 4 files but like I say, are .scss not css.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the content of the file scss (the content is not compiled) or is just the extension of the files?

Comment: @animalitomaquina Yes, I should have said, the content is also the content of the scss files just merged together

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've found the problem. One of the SCSS files is referencing a path to another file which I've misspelled the path to!

Corrected and working now

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the closing of your first pipe, you should close it before starting the pipe for gulp.dest.

By doing so the files should be compiled to css and not scss.

```
.pipe(sass({
    includePaths: [
        "govuk_modules/govuk_frontend_toolkit/stylesheets/",
        "govuk_modules/govuk_template/assets/stylesheet/",
        "govuk_modules/govuk-elements-sass/"
    ]
})).pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/stylesheets/"));
```